# Firestore requests are erroring out with status: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My Firestore read requests are getting errored out. I believe that some sort of incorrect blacklisting has happened.

Environment: development

Purpose: To find a document  in my Firestore collection named "auth"

Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
}
}
```

Firestore Schema:

```
Collection name: auth
Document: <email id> eg: test@example.com
Fields: name, role
```

Code:

```
let docRef = doc(db, "auth", newUserEmail.value); // <email id>
let docSnap;
try {
docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
} catch(error) {
console.log("error: ", error);
}
```

Error message:
error:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I get the same error message irrespective of whether the document that I'm looking up is present or not.

Finally, I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting as Firestore has no logging system visible to developers and there are no flags on my web console.

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is no document by the name you requested, or the user doesn't have permission to access it.  We can't really help you without knowing more.  For example, we don't know the path of the document being accessed (we can't see the value of `newUserEmail.value`), nor can we see that you have a document in the auth collection with that ID.  Also we can't tell if a user is signed in at the time the request was made, because your rules definitely require that.  Please edit the question to explain in full detail how anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the question with my schema and additional context. Appreciate your help.

Comment: We still can't see the value of `newUserEmail.value` or the actual contents of your database that are supposed to match. We also still can't see that there is a user signed in at the time of the query, as required by your rules.

Comment: Kind of off topic but using email addresses as documentId's may be problematic.  email addresses change and if that happens, every reference to that that document will have to be deleted and updated, as well as the document itself having to be deleted and re-written (DocumentId's cannot be changed). The string may have to be parsed to remove any formatting or illegal characters. See [Firebase Usage and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields). It's often big pain. Better to use the users uid as the documentId because it's static.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson 
My query is supposed to work even if a user isn't logged in. How do I update my rules to support both scenarios: when a user is logged in and when a user isn't logged in?

newUserEmail.value is Vue.JS ref variable, treat it as a string value.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug  asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on inputs from @Doug, I realized that my rules were not permitting requests from unauthenticated users in the new login/registration pages which was exactly where the issue occurred.

I've updated my rules to,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /auth/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear, well-explained solution to your own question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!